Rsync - Sync two directories without changing mode and ownership of either
Let's say I start with following a/ and b/ directories,
ls -l a/ b/                                                                                                                                         
a/:
total 4
-rw--w-rw- 1 783 783 11 Aug  6 18:57 x

b/:
total 4
-rw-r--rw- 1 1234 1234 3 Aug  6 18:57 x

Using rsync,
rsync -a --no-group --no-owner --no-perms a/ b
Expected result:
ls -l a/ b/                                                                                                                                         
a/:
total 4
-rw--w-rw- 1 783 783 11 Aug  6 18:57 x

b/:
total 4
-rw-r--rw- 1 1234 1234 11 Aug  6 18:57 x

Actual result:
ls -l a/ b/                                                                                                                                         
a/:
total 4
-rw--w-rw- 1 783 783 11 Aug  6 18:57 x

b/:
total 4
-rw-r--rw- 1 iresh iresh 11 Aug  6 18:57 x

While rsync certainly doesn't sync the permissions and the ownership, it still changes at least the destination file's ownership.
Is it possible portable solution to achieve the expected result using rsync or similar tool?

With --inplace (and obviously, as root, unless the rsync running user are permitted to write the file(s) in concern) you should get what want, although it has caveats that might or might not concern you.

@TomYan That is the answer. I'd appreciate if you could post this as an answer perhaps with the caveats.

Well, I'm not that familiar with rsync / --inplace. It's probably better for you to check out the details about it yourself in the man page. I only faintly remember seeing that there may be things one needs to note / be careful about in certain cases.
